# CSS inline styling ignores hover effect

Tags: css, inline-styles

I was just playing around with CSS and noticed an interesting scenario for which I couldn't really find an explanation. Maybe some of you have the answer for this.

I have a div element with an inline styling

```
<div id="text-sample" style="overflow:hidden;">This is a sample text to test the CSS behavior of inline styling</div>
```

My CSS

```
#text-sample {
    width:200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#text-sample:hover {
    overflow:visible
}
```

Here the hover effect is not applying. That is, the `overflow: visible` rule is not taking.

> Note: Moving the overflow:hidden from inline style will fix the issue.

I'm looking for the reason why hover effect is not applying. Can anyone explain this scenario?

Comment: check in console if hover is fired; check if css property is not overwritten.

Comment: try to change the width &  nowrap on hover also !

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, inline styles take precedence over styles applied via stylesheet rules. In your case, when hovering, the `overflow: visible` is invoked via the stylesheet rule, but that cannot override the inline style. If necessary, you could try `!important`.

```css
#text-sample {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#text-sample:hover {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="text-sample" style="overflow:hidden;">
  This is a sample text to test the CSS behavior of inline styling
</div>
```

But it would be easier simply to specify `overflow: hidden` in the `#text-sample` stylesheet rule, instead of giving it inline.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. adding important is working.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline style will always override your external CSS.
You can use `!important` in `:hover`

```
#text-sample {
  width:200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#text-sample:hover {
  overflow:visible!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles take precedence over style sheets. There are two ways to change that: using JavaScript or using `!important` in the style sheet.

```
#text-sample:hover {
   overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Got but try not to use !important

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, there's something called [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Simply said, something like

```
#id { color: red; }
```

would take precedence over something like

```
.blue { color: red; }
```

when having something like `<div id="id" class="blue">`. See example below.
This is because an ID selector (`#`) is interpreted as more important than a class. In the same manner, an equally specific selector with a later declaration (later in the file) takes precedence and the more specific your selector gets, the more important it is.

For your example: An inline-style takes precedence over anything written in a CSS file (unless using `!important`). I believe the `:hover` does not change anything on that fact.

For the detailed rules look my link above.

```css
div {
    width:200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#text-sample:hover,
#sample-2:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}

#sample-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#foo {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="text-sample" style="overflow:hidden;">This is a sample text to test the CSS behavior of inline styling</div>

<div id="sample-2">This is a sample text to test the CSS behavior of inline styling</div>

<div id="foo" class="blue">foo</div>
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments, Specificity does not apply to inline styles. Nevertheless, inline styles are taking precedence over anything in a CSS declarations in files. However, as soon as you move the rule into the same CSS file (as you mentioned will work), the `:hover` is more important than the other rule since it is more specific in the moment you're hovering.

Comment: Inline styles have nothing to do with specificity. Specificity applies to rules in stylesheets. Whether or not a given style is applied is based first on whether it's inline, then if a stylesheet rule applies, on that rule's specificity. This particular problem is unrelated to specificity.

Comment: @torazaburo I see, I did not know the word does not apply. But since inline styles are the most specific you can get, I think this does not change the general conclusion of my answer (inline takes precedence).

Comment: @torazaburo Updated my posting. I think this should be okay.